# system command to open a file in r

Tags: r

need help to open a file in system directory like pdf file in 
`path ="c:\\abc\\xyz.pdf"` with system default pdf viewer
Or to open image in folder using system default photo viewer 
already try `system('"E:\\pdf_ka_zakhera\\9780387981406-c1.pdf"')` in R

Comment: An appropriate web search should yield some advice, which you can try and share where exactly you are stuck in this question.

Comment: actually doing text mining. i'm stuck i want open file in directory like a link

Comment: Please refine your question, for example, what language are you working in, give us a concrete step by step description of the process your trying to model.  It would also help if you described what you've already tried and what the results to those attempts where, there is simply too little information in your existing post to determine the best way to help you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
shell("E:\\pdf_ka_zakhera\\9780387981406-c1.pdf")
```

From "shell" help page:

> To make use of Windows file associations, use `shell.exec`