# Import synced OneDrive files

Tags: r, sharepoint, shiny, synchronization, onedrive

For a project I want to create a shinydashboard that is powered by data provided by various people in a SharePoint and has the ability to automatically update once a file is edited in SharePoint.

Because of firewall issues with the company I am working for it seemed like a better idea to sync the SharePoint folder to my local disk, and upload the files from there.

My code looks like this:

```
observe({
  invalidateLater(2000, session)
  list <- list.files(path = "../../folder/folder", pattern = ".xlsx", recursive = T)
  for (i in 1:length(list)) {
    assign(basename(file_path_sans_ext(list[i])), 
           as.data.table(read_xlsx(paste0("../../folder/folder/", list[i]))))
  }
})
```

By itself the code works well. It grabs all of the documents and assigns them to data.tables with their filename as name. However, whenever I make a change to one of the documents in SharePoint it won't update the file in my local disk until I open it manually. I can see that because when I the Preview Pane in file explorer it will still show the unedited document.

**My question:**
Is there a way in R to force a sync or in OneDrive to sync automatically once an update is made to the original file? All files combined are like 250kb so even if an automatic update might be too heavy in most cases, I think it's fine in my case.

Comment: You can right-click on the folder/file that you want to keep updated and select "Always keep on this device".

Comment: I gave it an attempt. However, the problem still persists

Comment: Have you tried disabling Files on Demand? (I can't change my group policy so I can't test if this would actually work).  See the second, non-accepted answer: https://superuser.com/questions/1151464/how-to-force-onedrive-to-synchronize

Comment: Have you tried using ``system`` or ``shell``? Perhaps this post will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33646625/system-command-to-open-a-file-in-r

Comment: @brandonEm I looked into shell but there are some limitations that I am wondering about. I manage to open the files using `shell` but I can only close them using `TASKKILL` which appears to be very slow/crashing my R. Also the files are opening in the front, would it be possible to have them open in the background? The PC that would run the dashboard will 24/7 have the dashboard open in browser for people to look at. Seeing Excel files open on the forefront is not a possible solution.

Comment: @Marcus this did not solve the issue

Comment: @WietsedeVries if you think the `shell` method is promising then you could follow up with this question on a Windows-focused board, e.g. [this post.](https://serverfault.com/questions/307385/taskkill-very-slow) I'm much more of a linux person so I'm afraid I have no clever answers past that. Good luck!